# Can someone explain ref( ) vs & in c++11 and when to use each?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, std

I read the documentation on it but if someone could explain it a little more plain english I would appreciate it.

Comment: [Example of using `std::ref` with `std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref#Example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plain C++ reference `&` is an odd citizen, because it can be initialized but not re-assigned. E.g.:

```
int a, &ra = a;
int b, &rb = b;
ra = rb; // actually does a = b
```

Whereas plain pointer is a well-behaved citizen, it can be both initialized and re-assigned.

Hence `ref()` creates [`reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) which is a wrapper over a plain pointer. This wrapper can be initialized with a reference and it has an automatic conversion to plain reference `&`, e.g.:

```
int a;
auto ra = std::ref(a); 
int b;
auto rb = std::ref(b);
ra = rb; // now ra contains a pointer to b
int& rb2 = ra; // automatically converts to reference
```

It is mainly useful for functional style programming with lambdas or `std::bind` expressions. `std::bind` copies bound arguments, so if you'd like to bind a function argument to a reference `reference_wrapper` comes handy. E.g.:

```
void foo(int);

int i = 1;
auto f = std::bind(foo, i); // makes a copy of i
i = 2;
f(); // calls foo(1)

auto g = std::bind(foo, std::ref(i));
i = 3;
g(); // calls foo(3);
```